# What are the needed math knowledge to understand diffusion models?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to understand formula (3) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf.

What are the needed math knowledge?

Comment: Looks like a standard introduction to mathematical statistics would cover it.

Comment: Thanks Galen! Do you have a recommended book?